# What's the Future of Lift framework and current work being done?

Tags: scala, frameworks, lift

I keep reading the developments being done on frameworks like Grails and other Java frameworks but not much of a buzz in the Lift camp. And also Lift 1.0 was announced long back. Is the community working on Lift framework? What are the future prospects of the framework? Is it better than Grails and other Java frameworks? (Groovy being less performing than Scala).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the little I read recently, Lift 1.1 should probably be out before Scala 2.8. As in, real soon now. There is a lot of activity on the Lift front, but they really do seem to be a bit more insular than other projects. I hear way more about Akka than about Lift, which I find really surprising. In fact, I hear way more about the general support of the Lift community for non-Lift Scala projects than I hear about Lift itself.

It's not that they aren't receptive and newbie-friendly or anything like that. I think it is just a matter of not having many personalities that are talkative about what they do, or, perhaps, those personalities are just in completely different circles than the ones I follow on the Internet.

It does bother me a bit that they don't have anyone strong here on Stack Overflow. If you compare the answers from Scala related question to those of Scala & Lift related questions, the difference is striking.

**Update Nov 16, 2010**

Just to update, Lift 2.0 was released and only works with Scala 2.7.7. Lift 2.1 followed it, though, and is available for both 2.7.7 and 2.8.0 (I suppose it works with 2.8.1 as well, but I haven't tested that). Beyond that, there's already a milestone available for Lift 2.2, so everything is going just fine.

Comment: Most questions about Lift are asked on the list.  That's where most of the developers are, and users as well.

Comment: Agree. I usually follow links on DZone. I get to see a lot of Grails related posts but very few or almost none Lift related blog posts. Hope we get to hear a lot about Lift in the coming Year

Answer (score 5):

I'm on the lift list, and get quite a few emails per day.  Quite a lot of interesting discussions, and M8 just rolled out.
So, in addition to the mailing list, looking at the [wiki](http://wiki.github.com/dpp/liftweb), and the [github](http://github.com/dpp/liftweb) repository you'll find all kinds of stuff.

Comment: Am starting off with Scala and Lift. Wanted to have a view of the developers in general. Great to hear about the work.

Comment: Then head on over to the mailing list Steve provided a link and join!
dpp, and the rest are all there!

Answer (score 3):

There's a very active [mailing list for lift](http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb). Perhaps you could peruse its archives and send an inquiry there if you're not satisfied with what you find.

Answer (score -1):

I've some experience with Grails and looked at Lift recently, but I find the programming model of lift somewhat strange and unintuitive. I'd prefer Scala over Groovy, but I'd choose Grails though (which has a Scala plug-in). Grails offers much more than Lift does. Grails is developed by SpringSource whereas no big company is behind Lift.

If you simply want to develop web applications choose Grails. If you're a Scala enthusiast go with Lift.

Comment: I didn't mean it like that. I respect the work of the Lift developers and just want to say that there is no big company behind the framework.

Comment: I suggest you look at the book (it's in PDF if you do not want to spend the money), the mailing list, and the wiki within the Liftweb github and you'll see it's gotten quite a bit farther than even just six months ago.